# want to store elements in array or list using python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

I am learning python. I want to store one by one element in array or list.
this is my code.

```
for u in durl:
      p2 = requests.get(u)
      tree = html.fromstring(p2.content)
      dcode.append = tree.xpath(ecode)
      print(dcode)
```

in dcode variable the elements are overriding not appending.
i want to insert it one by one.
please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append vs. extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

Answer (score 2):

append is a method not a variable so if you want to append `tree.xpath(ecode)` to `dcode` then you should write `dcode.append(tree.xpath(ecode))` rather than `dcode.append =` which is an assignment not a method call.

Answer (score 0):

`tree.xpath(...)` returns a list so if you want to merge it with an existing list `dcode` of selected elements, you might do

```
dcode.extend(tree.xpath(ecode))
```

Comment: but it was giving again error like dcode is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, it appends new value to the list and it makes more sense...sort of data structure

```
def main(decode=[]):
  for u in durl:
      p2 = requests.get(u)
      tree = html.fromstring(p2.content)
      dcode.append(tree.xpath(ecode))
      print(dcode)
```